# Align asymmetrical polygons in manim

Tags: centering, cairo, manim, pycairo

I've learned to draw (via verticies) a number of asymmetrical polygons in Manim.  (if it matters, the shapes I'm concerned with are the values "longa", "brevis", "semibrevis" and "minima" in this chart: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/MensuralNotation.JPG
)

Some of them are symmetrical shapes (like ♢ or □) which are easy to align and manipulate in manim.  Some however are asymmetrical (like "p" or "d") but their center/axis-of-rotation/point-of-alignment are not the center of vertices but another point (like the center of the bowl of the "p" or "d").

I'd like to have a series of VMobjects like "p ♢ □ d" all align on their defined centers (for "p" and "d" I constructed the polygons so that their origins should be the center).  I've tried overriding `get_center()` and trying to align objects to the ORIGIN but (even after performing a `.shift()`) all objects assigned to align_to, next_to, etc. and a VGroup surrounding the object all ignore the center.

Is there a way to more forcefully assign the center for an object?

(Manim community fork, latest as of March 10, 2022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the internal alignment methods (when using the Cairo renderer) use the [`get_critical_point`](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/blob/ef00ae5e668907eac2ae18c19c35e78671ccfcc2/manim/mobject/mobject.py#L1850) method of `Mobject` to determine the special points of a mobject that should be used for alignment. If you'd like to pursue your override-approach, then I'd recommend overriding that one.

If it is really just the custom center you would like to override, then something like

```
def get_critical_point(self, direction):
    if np.array_equal(direction, [0, 0, 0]):
        return self.custom_center
    return super().get_critical_point(direction)
```

might already work.

It is possible that this breaks some other things though, so I can't quite tell whether it would be better overall to just implement and use some sort of custom auxiliary functions for alignment and then work with those.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Benjamin Hackl -- I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Thank you!  This worked immediately for at least the simple cases that were frustrating me -- I think I can go from there for quite some time.  For others reading, it was more important to override `get_critical_point` for `ORIGIN` than it was to override `get_center()` -- it seems that a lot more down the road consults `get_critical_point(ORIGIN)` than looks at `get_center()`

Comment: @MichaelScottAsatoCuthbert indeed, not surprising [considering that `get_center` also uses `get_critical_point`](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/blob/ef00ae5e668907eac2ae18c19c35e78671ccfcc2/manim/mobject/mobject.py#L1887) internally. :-)

Comment: @MichaelScottAsatoCuthbert just a brief reminder to mark the answer to the question as correct if it resolved your issue. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten! For OpenGL renderer this doesn’t work but there’s a different method to override instead.

Comment: Yup, OpenGLMobject is build a bit differently, the critical points are called bounding box points there (which is more natural anyways). But you seem to have found that out regardless. :-)